# i want to load the data from openweathermap so i can display it but am getting Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

i created a div with the id 'temporary' so i will be able to insert the data from the openweathermap.org API but i am getting an error at the console  and i don't know why. I am new to loading data from API. here is the full html code [jsfiddle code here](https://jsfiddle.net/mameddram/z4Lar20b/)

here is the script where the error occured

````
var data;

$("form").click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  loadJson();
});

function loadJson(){
  loadJson("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&appid=b7e1c74ddc5f04e3e18d2ce29e5d432c&units=metric", displayData);
};

function displayData(temp){
  data = temp;

  $("#temporary").html(data);
};
</script> ```
````

Comment: [1] `loadJson` calls [2] `loadJson`, then [2] `loadJson` calls [3] `loadJson` indefinitely. It's an inifite loop.

Comment: how can I correct that?

Comment: `loadJson` is endlessly recursive. What do you think its supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your function loadJson call itself while your stack is not exceeded.

Rewrite this function so that it loads json and does not call itself indefinitely

Comment: what can i do so i can load the data from the API correctly

Comment: You can do load json any way- xhr, fetch, socket connection etc

Answer (score 0):

You should use different name

```
var data;

$("form").click(function(evt){
  evt.preventDefault();
  anotherNameForLoadJson();
});

function anotherNameForLoadJson(){
  loadJson("https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&appid=b7e1c74ddc5f04e3e18d2ce29e5d432c&units=metric", displayData);
};

function displayData(temp){
  data = temp;

  $("#temporary").html(data);
};
```